# Wordpress Tags in class

Tags: loop, tags, slug, post-class

I have added tags to my Custom Post Type.
Now I want to use them to create a isotope portfolio, I can load all tags with this code:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 24;
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="all <?php echo $tag->slug; ?>">
        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But now I want to add the all tags that from each portfolio item to the `class=""`.
With `<div class="<?php $tag->slug; ?>">` I just get the last tag of all the tags that are used.

I know there are already a lot of posts about this problem, but every post I have found does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you getting these tags from? Typically, to get a list of tags attached to a post, you'd do:

```
$some_tags =  wp_get_post_tags( $post_id);
```

and then itterate through as such:

```
foreach($some_tags as $tag) {
do stuff 
}
```

Comment: I'm Getting those from <?php $tags = get_tags(); ?>, I have that above the loop where i'm getting all the tags so you can click on it to filter.

Comment: Okay, can you do a var_dump($tags) and post what outputs? My guess is, you aren't itterating through the tags properly, as I showed above.

Comment: This do i get from my var_dump [http://pastebin.com/Y5prpYUF](http://pastebin.com/Y5prpYUF) and a screenshot from the wp-admin tags page [http://snag.gy/2q2NW.jpg](http://snag.gy/2q2NW.jpg)

Comment: you could probably use the `wp_get_post_tags` along with `wp_list_pluck` to pull out the specific property and then `implode` the result for your list of classes.

Comment: When I use (wp_get_post_tags), I get the following error: `Undefined variable: wp_get_post_tags`. If I use (get_tags), I get all the tags that are used. But I only need the tags within the loop.

Comment: It now works with the following code: `<?php $tags = get_the_tags(); $tag = wp_list_pluck( $tags, 'slug' ); $tagToClass = implode(" ", $tag); ?>`

Comment: Oh, my bad, tags are sorted in an object. You can iterate through as usual, it'd look like this:

foreach($tags as $tag) {
$tag->whatever_variable_you_address;
}